# Determining the time at which a date starts

Tags: perl, date, datetime, time, timezone

Say I want to create a daily planner, and I want to divide the day into 15 minute chunks.

Easy, right? Just start at midnight, and... Wrong! In America/Sao_Paulo, one day each year starts at 01:00 because of Daylight Saving Time changes.

Given a time zone and a date, how does one find the epoch time at which the day starts?

My first thought was to use the following, but it assumes each day has a 23:59. That's probably no better of an assumption than assuming each day has a midnight.

```
perl -MDateTime -E'
   say
      DateTime->new( year => 2013, month => 10, day => 20 )
      ->subtract( days => 1 )
      ->set( hour => 23, minute => 59 )
      ->set_time_zone("America/Sao_Paulo")
      ->add( minutes => 1 )
      ->strftime("%H:%M");
'
01:00
```

Is there a more robust or more direct alternative?

Comment: Hmmm. Are you sure every day ends at 23:59?

Comment: @mob, Good point. I may not have a working solution at all.

Comment: You need to set timezone in the 'new'. You loosing hour because time zone shift, I guess.

Comment: @alex, You misunderstand. `01:00` is the correct answer. While you "spring forward" into DST at 2am in Maryland (I'm guessing), they spring forward at midnight in Sao Paulo.

Comment: Yes, it is: http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zoneinfo?tz=America/Sao_Paulo So many exceptions.

Comment: @alex, I'm looking for a better way of doing this, especially now that I'm not sure that what I posted is always correct.

Comment: On Feb 16, 2013, it appears that there are two times when it is 23:59.

Comment: Interesting question.  I recommend you think about this as two separate concepts: (1) The time instant (in UTC) at which the day begins, and (2) how that instant is represented in the local timezone.  This may help clarify the problem.  In the forward instance the first time instant of the new day occurs one second after 23:59:59 with no discontinuity, but is "named" 01:00:00 and that day is only 23 hours long.  In the other case the start of the day occurs 1 hour and 1 second after the first 23:59:59 and is named 00:00:00. The _previous_ day is 25 hours long.

Comment: @Jim Garrison, I agree 100%. It's indeed the epoch time one wants here. It's representation in local time is a (trivially) derived value.

Comment: In which case the problem becomes one of identifying which day is 23 hours long and which is 25 hours long.

Comment: Assuming that you've seen these: http://www.houseabsolute.com/presentations/dates-times-perl-and-you/#38 (a good presentation by Rolsky) and http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.datetime/2012/06/msg7854.html. Putting them here in case others are interested in reading some context. Also see Rolsky's comment here: http://grokbase.com/t/perl/datetime/094rwk5bw2/serious-problem-datetime-timezone-0-89-when-set-to-africa-cairo-throws-exception-right-now.

Comment: @FMc, I hadn't, but I'm quite familiar with the principles put forward in (1), I know how to work around the problem in (2) (which is to use `now`, switch to the floating time zone, then truncate to day), and (3) is what I had in mind in my earlier comment to Vector Gorgoth (though it's not particularly relevant here as I'm doing date-time arithmetic, not date arithmetic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*This functionality is now available from [DateTimeX::Start](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTimeX::Start)*]

Here's a solution using only DT's public methods:

```
sub day_start {
   my ($y, $m, $d, $tz) = @_;

   $tz = DateTime::TimeZone->new( name => $tz )
      if !ref($tz);

   my $dt = DateTime->new( year => $y, month => $m, day => $d );
   my $target_day = ( $dt->utc_rd_values )[0];
   my $min_epoch = int($dt->epoch()/60) - 24*60;
   my $max_epoch = int($dt->epoch()/60) + 24*60;
   while ($max_epoch > $min_epoch) {
      my $epoch = ( $min_epoch + $max_epoch ) >> 1;
      $dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $epoch*60, time_zone => $tz );
      if (( $dt->local_rd_values )[0] < $target_day) {
         $min_epoch = $epoch;
      } else {
         $max_epoch = $epoch;
      }
   }

   return DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => $max_epoch*60, time_zone => $tz);
}
```

Since most dates do have a midnight, a check should be added at the top to bypass the search when it's not needed.

Assumptions:

- There is no dt to which one can add time to obtain a dt with an earlier date.
- In no time zone does a date starts more than 24*60*60 seconds before the date starts in UTC.
- In no time zone does a date starts more than 24*60*60 seconds after the date starts in UTC.
- Jumps in time zones only occur on times with zero seconds. (Optimization)

Test:

```
{
    # No midnight.
    my $tz = DateTime::TimeZone->new( name => 'America/Sao_Paulo' );
    my $dt = day_start(2013, 10, 20, $tz);
    print($dt->epoch, " ", $dt->iso8601, "\n");  # 1382238000 2013-10-20T01:00:00
    $dt->subtract( seconds => 1 );
    print($dt->epoch, " ", $dt->iso8601, "\n");  # 1382237999 2013-10-19T23:59:59
}

{
    # Two midnights.
    my $tz = DateTime::TimeZone->new( name => 'America/Havana' );
    my $dt = day_start(2013, 11, 3, $tz);
    print($dt->epoch, " ", $dt->iso8601, "\n");  # 1383451200 2013-11-03T00:00:00
    $dt->subtract( seconds => 1 );
    print($dt->epoch, " ", $dt->iso8601, "\n");  # 1383451199 2013-11-02T23:59:59
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You'd think this is something that needs to be done commonly! I suspect there's a lot of buggy code out there...

Here's a solution that's coded with the intention of trying to get it incorporated into DateTime.

```
use strict;
use warnings;


use DateTime           qw( );
use DateTime::TimeZone qw( );


# Assumption:
#    There is no dt to which one can add time
#    to obtain a dt with an earlier date.

sub day_start {
    my $tz = shift;
    my $dt = shift;

    my $local_rd_days = ( $dt->local_rd_values() )[0];
    my $seconds = $local_rd_days * 24*60*60;

    my $min_idx;
    if ( $seconds < $tz->max_span->[DateTime::TimeZone::LOCAL_END] ) {
        $min_idx = 0;
    } else {
        $min_idx = @{ $tz->{spans} };
        $tz->_generate_spans_until_match( $dt->utc_year()+1, $seconds, 'local' );
    }

    my $max_idx = $#{ $tz->{spans} };

    my $utc_rd_days;
    my $utc_rd_secs;
    while (1) {
        my $current_idx = int( ( $min_idx + $max_idx )/2 );
        my $current = $tz->{spans}[$current_idx];

        if ( $seconds < $current->[DateTime::TimeZone::LOCAL_START] ) {
            $max_idx = $current_idx - 1;
        }
        elsif ( $seconds >= $current->[DateTime::TimeZone::LOCAL_END] ) {
            $min_idx = $current_idx + 1;
        }
        else {
            my $offset = $current->[DateTime::TimeZone::OFFSET];

            # In case of overlaps, always prefer earlier span.
            if ($current->[DateTime::TimeZone::IS_DST] && $current_idx) {
                my $prev = $tz->{spans}[$current_idx-1];
                $offset = $prev->[DateTime::TimeZone::OFFSET]
                    if $seconds >= $prev->[DateTime::TimeZone::LOCAL_START]
                    && $seconds < $prev->[DateTime::TimeZone::LOCAL_END];
            }

            $utc_rd_days = $local_rd_days;
            $utc_rd_secs = -$offset;
            DateTime->_normalize_tai_seconds($utc_rd_days, $utc_rd_secs);
            last;
        }

        if ($min_idx > $max_idx) {
            $current_idx = $min_idx;
            $current = $tz->{spans}[$current_idx];

            if (int( $current->[DateTime::TimeZone::LOCAL_START] / (24*60*60) ) != $local_rd_days) {
                my $err = 'Invalid local time for date';
                $err .= " in time zone: " . $tz->name;
                $err .= "\n";
                die $err;
            }

            $utc_rd_secs = $current->[DateTime::TimeZone::UTC_START] % (24*60*60);
            $utc_rd_days = int( $current->[DateTime::TimeZone::UTC_START] / (24*60*60) );
            last;
        }
    }

    my ($year, $month, $day) = DateTime->_rd2ymd($utc_rd_days);
    my ($hour, $minute, $second) = DateTime->_seconds_as_components($utc_rd_secs);

    return
       $dt
         ->_new_from_self(
             year      => $year,
             month     => $month,
             day       => $day,
             hour      => $hour,
             minute    => $minute,
             second    => $second,
             time_zone => 'UTC',
         )
         ->set_time_zone($tz);
}
```

Test:

```
sub new_date {
    my $y = shift;
    my $m = shift;
    my $d = shift;
    return DateTime->new(
        year => $y, month => $m, day => $d,
        @_,
        hour => 0, minute => 0, second => 0, nanosecond => 0,
        time_zone => 'floating'
    );
}


{
    # No midnight.
    my $tz = DateTime::TimeZone->new( name => 'America/Sao_Paulo' );
    my $dt = day_start($tz, new_date(2013, 10, 20));
    print($dt->iso8601(), "\n");     # 2013-10-20T01:00:00
    $dt->subtract( seconds => 1 );
    print($dt->iso8601(), "\n");     # 2013-10-19T23:59:59
}

{
    # Two midnights.
    my $tz = DateTime::TimeZone->new( name => 'America/Havana' );
    my $dt = day_start($tz, new_date(2013, 11, 3));
    print($dt->iso8601(), "\n");     # 2013-11-03T00:00:00
    $dt->subtract( seconds => 1 );
    print($dt->iso8601(), "\n");     # 2013-11-02T23:59:59
}
```

A practical example,

```
sub today_as_floating {
    return
        DateTime
            ->now( @_ )
            ->set_time_zone('floating')
            ->truncate( to => 'day' );
}

{
    my $tz = DateTime::TimeZone->new( name => 'local' );
    my $dt = today_as_floating( time_zone => $tz );
    $dt = day_start($tz, $dt);
    print($dt->iso8601(), "\n");
}
```

Comment: I suggest you also do a `day_end` function, which should return midnight of the following day for most dates, but might return something like 11 PM on the same day for certain cases.  (Don't return 23:59:59, that will make a mess of things.)

Comment: @Matt Johnson, Trivial: `sub day_end { day_start($_[0], $_[1]->clone->add( days => 1 )) }`. A day would be defined by the interval `[day_start,day_end)`.

Comment: Nice work, it would definitely be a nice addition to DateTime.

Answer (score 3):

A reasonable approach would be to start at 12:00 PM (noon) on that day, and work backwards incrementally until the date changed.  The same going forward to find the end of the day.

Noon is appropriate, because (AFAIK) all time zones that have DST changes transition in the middle of the night, to minimize the impact on human beings.  Presumably, the vast majority of people are awake during the day, so governments would be foolish to set DST changes during business hours.

You would want to move in 15 minute increments to cover all bases.  There are some time zones with :30 or :45 minute offsets, and some that only change by 30 minutes for DST.

Now if you are going back into antiquity, this isn't the best solution because many time zones had adjustments for other reasons than DST - such as initial synchronization with UTC, which could be by some odd minutes or seconds value.  So this should work fine with reasonably present dates, but not for all past dates.

If you want something that is less linear, then the algorithm would have to determine the interval of the boundaries for the time zone rule that the date fell into, then use those to check if they fall on the day in question or not.  In the [source code for `Datetime::TimeZone`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/DROLSKY/DateTime-TimeZone-1.63/lib/DateTime/TimeZone.pm), I see that it defines an internal concept of a "span".  You could use `DateTime::TimeZone->_span_for_datetime` to find the span that the date in question fell into, and then check the start and end dates from there.

I am not a Perl programmer, so I'll leave that exercise to you or someone else.  Besides, I checked and the values in the span don't appear to be unix timestamps, so I'm not quite sure how to take it from there - and they appear to be undocumented/internal so I don't think that's necessarily a good idea in Perl anyway.

Comment: Indeed, I was looking the source earlier, and thought I might create a patch or an extension module to address this problem. (Note that the name of the language is "Perl", not "PERL". It's not an acronym.)

Comment: Also, FYI - most date/time APIs in other languages do not have this ability either, so this approach is indeed what you would do in Python, PHP, C#, Java, and others.

Comment: You may be interested in the answer I [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20850899/589924).

Answer (score 3):

[Time::Local](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html)'s `timelocal()` function is clever enough to do the right thing here if you ask for the epoch time for midnight. For 2014, DST changes are as follows:

```
$ zdump -v America/Sao_Paulo | fgrep 2014
America/Sao_Paulo  Sun Feb 16 01:59:59 2014 UTC = Sat Feb 15 23:59:59 2014 BRST isdst=1 gmtoff=-7200
America/Sao_Paulo  Sun Feb 16 02:00:00 2014 UTC = Sat Feb 15 23:00:00 2014 BRT isdst=0 gmtoff=-10800
America/Sao_Paulo  Sun Oct 19 02:59:59 2014 UTC = Sat Oct 18 23:59:59 2014 BRT isdst=0 gmtoff=-10800
America/Sao_Paulo  Sun Oct 19 03:00:00 2014 UTC = Sun Oct 19 01:00:00 2014 BRST isdst=1 gmtoff=-7200
```

So midnight is "missing" on 2014-10-19. However, if we actually ask for the epoch time for that anyway, and then convert it back into a local time:

```
$ TZ=America/Sao_Paulo perl -MTime::Local -E 'say scalar localtime(timelocal(0, 0, 0, 19, 9, 114))'
Sun Oct 19 01:00:00 2014
```

And one second before:

```
$ TZ=America/Sao_Paulo perl -MTime::Local -E 'say scalar localtime(timelocal(0, 0, 0, 19, 9, 114)-1)'
Sat Oct 18 23:59:59 2014
```

Comment: Excellent! Or it would be if it didn't fail for days with two midnights. (It gives the latter one.) e.g. 2013-11-03 in America/Havana give 1383454800 instead of 1383451200

Answer (score 1):

One (cumbersome) possible solution: figure out a conservative time (say, 23:00:00 or 23:50:00--the only important part is that no date past or future should roll over before this time), and then increment that time until the date changes:

```
#Assume $year/$month/$day contain the date one day prior to the target date
my $dt = DateTime->new(
    time_zone => $tz,
    year => $year,
    month => $month,
    day => $day,
    hour => 23,
    minute => 59,
    second => 0,
);
while($dt->year == $year && $dt->month == $month && $dt->day == $day) {
    $dt->add(seconds => 1);
}
#At this point $dt should, if I understand the functioning of DateTime correctly, contain the earliest "valid" time in the target date.
```

I'm 100% sure there is a better solution to this; the ideal would be if DateTime defaulted to the earliest valid time for a given time zone, given a date with no time--currently it defaults to zero for all of those values, and I'm not certain that it will correct the value if it's not valid for that TZ. If it does internally correct those values, then that solution would be vastly preferable; it might be worth contacting the maintainer of DateTime to see what the actual behaviour is, and if said behaviour is guaranteed in the future if it is currently the desired behaviour.

Comment: That's basically the same as what I posted, but far less efficient. True, I could start at an earlier time like you suggested, at which point a binary search would be more efficient than a linear search.

Comment: Re "the ideal would be if DateTime defaulted to the earliest valid time for a given time zone, given a date with no time", That would go entirely against DateTime's model.

Comment: @ikegami No, not really. The zero default for optional inputs is an intelligent approach and _usually_ will result in a the earliest valid time for a given date. It is a convention of time measurement _generally_ that unspecified units are zeroed; that's why "twelve o'clock" means 12:00:00, not 12:xx:xx. This would simply be extending the concept to ensure that the values are the minimum valid inputs, which is really the only intelligent approach anyway.

Comment: @ikegami Re efficiency, yes, this is not optimized, but a second-granular approach will be mandatory if one wants to catch all the potential problems. In fact, a truly comprehensive search across all dates would have to be very clever in order to be both correct and efficient, far too clever to really fit in a SO answer.

Comment: @ikegami Addendum to DateTime model: unspecified is different from specifying invalid values; if I do `hours => 0, seconds => 0, minutes => 0` that is entirely different from omitting them entirely.

Comment: Your addendum is news to me, it's contrary to the documentation, and it's not supported by a comparision of a dump of `DateTime->new(year=>1970,month=>1,day=>1)` with a dump of `DateTime->new(year=>1970,month=>1,day=>1,hour=>0)`. Could you back up your claim by demonstrating a difference?

Comment: Re "No, not really", Yes, really. midnight + 1 day gives midinight the next day according to DateTime model. If the next day does not have an midnight, then the operation cannot be performed. Returning 1am is not correct. 1am is not one day later. If it gave 1am, then x + a + a != x + 2*a, and that makes no sense.

Comment: Semantically different, not different in DateTime code, which is strictly speaking an issue with DateTime. And making such operations impossible is also a failing of DateTime; it is both inconsistent with any common sense notion of time and also creates code which is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @ikegami https://www.mail-archive.com/datetime@perl.org/msg06358.html This is the perfect example of why the current behaviour in DateTime is hosed.

Comment: If you want to deal with dates (as opposed to date-times), you gotta switch to the floating TZ. That addresses the problem in the linked message.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DateTime::TimeZone](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime%3a%3aTimeZone) directly to query for a valid local time. DateTime::TimeZone raises an exception if the local time does not exist due to a nearby offset change.

```
use DateTime;
use DateTime::TimeZone;

my $zone = DateTime::TimeZone->new(name => 'America/Sao_Paulo');
my $dt   = DateTime->new(year => 2013, month => 10, day => 20);

sub valid_local_time {
    eval { $zone->offset_for_local_datetime($dt) };
    return $@ !~ /^Invalid local time/;
}

while (!valid_local_time()) {
    $dt->add(minutes => 15);
}

$dt->set_time_zone($zone);

sub local_time_lt {
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    return $x->local_rd_as_seconds < $y->local_rd_as_seconds;
}

sub local_time_eq {
    my ($x, $y) = @_;
    return $x->local_rd_as_seconds == $y->local_rd_as_seconds;
}

my $copy = $dt->clone->subtract(seconds => 1);
if (local_time_lt($dt, $copy)) {
    my $delta = $copy->local_rd_as_seconds - $dt->local_rd_as_seconds;
    local_time_eq($dt, $copy->subtract(seconds => $delta))
      or die qq/Could not determine start of day ($dt [${\$zone->name}])/;
    $dt = $copy;
}

print $dt->strftime('%H:%M'), "\n";
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that will give the wrong time when they are two midnights. e.g. 2013-11-03 in America/Havana. (Subtract a second from the result and you'll see why it's wrong.)

Comment: @ikegami It's only possible to detect invalid times using DateTime::TimeZone. In the case of ambiguous times, DateTime::TimeZone  silently chooses the latest possible standard time.

Comment: The answer is definitely non-trivial. See the answer I posted.

Comment: @ikegami, I think I have have working solution using publicly available API, passes the two tests in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is everyone missing the really obvious way to do it? It's midnight on the current day. I.e. set the seconds, minutes and hours to zero, and take the mday, mon and year fields from localtime.

```
use POSIX qw( mktime tzset );
$ENV{TZ} = 'America/Sao_Paulo';
tzset();
my $epoch = mktime( 0, 0, 0, 20, 10-1, 2013-1900 );
print localtime($epoch)."\n";   # Sun Oct 20 01:00:00 2013
```

Comment: Hrm - does the `mktime()` adjustment not fix for that? Since the day literally doesn't have a 00:00:00, it becomes 01:00:00?
If not, could you `localtime()` it and check it still had the same day - if not add that hour..?

Comment: Excellent! Or it would be if it didn't fail for days with two midnights. (It gives the latter one.) e.g. 2013-11-03 in America/Havana give 1383454800 instead of 1383451200. It also doesn't work on Winwdows.